# Как скрыть полосу прокрутки для IE?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, прокрутка

Простенький скроллинг изображений.
В Хроме работает превосходно - горизонтальной полосы прокрутки нет и ее не видно, движение изображений происходит по наведению мышки. 
В IE же скролинг виден и естественно по наведеню мышки ничего не движеться...

Существует ли на данный момент вариант решения этой вечной проблемы для  IE? Что нужно добавить в скрипте для правильной работы в IE?

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="ves_bizness.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css"> 
body {
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
}
div.sc_menu {
    position: relative;
    height: 73px;
    width: 895px;
    overflow: auto;
}
ul.sc_menu {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 10000px; 
    padding: 10px 0 0 10px; 
    margin: 0;
    background: url('vesbizness_bg.png');       
    list-style: none;
}
.sc_menu li {
    display: block;
    float: left;    
    padding: 0 4px;
}
.sc_menu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sc_menu span {
    display: none;
    margin-top: 3px;

    text-align: center;
    font:bold 12px Georgia, Arial, Helvetica;   
    color: #9c0a0d;
}
.sc_menu a:hover span {
    display: block;
}
.sc_menu img {
    border: 0px #dedede solid;  
    -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px;
}
.sc_menu a:hover img {
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);   
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#back {
    display: block;
    width: 900px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #003469;
    font-size: 16px;
}
</style> 
<script type= "text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/
$(function(){
    //
    var div = $('div.sc_menu'),
        ul = $('ul.sc_menu'),
        ulPadding = 15;

    //
    var divWidth = div.width();

    //  
    div.css({overflow: 'hidden'});

    //
    var lastLi = ul.find('li:last-child');

    //
    div.mousemove(function(e){

        var ulWidth = lastLi[0].offsetLeft + lastLi.outerWidth() + ulPadding;   
        var left = (e.pageX - div.offset().left) * (ulWidth-divWidth) / divWidth;
        div.scrollLeft(left);
    });
});
/*]]>*/</script>
```

Comment: Если сделать 
html { overflow-x: hidden; }

То прокрутки вообще не будет, и изображения выстраиваються в ряд с нарушением границ сайта...

Comment: Скрины бы показал, страница то не вся.

Comment: Там остались только <li> ...  </li>

Comment: выход такой, для тех кто еще пользуеться  IE стилизовать полосу прокрутки под сайт...

Comment: Если кто-то знает варианты организации кроссбраузерной прокрутки изображений на сайте